# Load data from PHP query into Modal

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, modal-dialog

Hi I have a modal in which I would like to dynamically load data received from a while loop, i am assigning id, yet the modal is only showing last row data (image).

This is my php

```
<script>
var slider_counter2 = 0;

</script>
<?php 
        $slide_counter1=0;
        while($data=$select->fetch()){ 
        $slide_counter1++; 
        ?>
<script>
slider_counter2++;

</script>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal_<?php echo $slide_counter1;?>" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->

    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" id="modal_close_btn_<?php echo $slide_counter1;?>">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <img class="propertylistboximgfilled" src="../images/user/final_<?php echo $data['property_image1'];?>">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modal.js"></script>

<?php } ?>
```

this is my javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal_'+slider_counter2);

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById('modalopener_'+slider_counter2);

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById('modal_close_btn_'+slider_counter2);

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

what could be wrong in this....

Comment: ok... i have put a simplified version of my problem here, i need to put a slider into my modal.. the slider will get 6 images from each "row" of data received from php while loop... can u guide me on that, I am using a jssor loop, please see this ... the code here works fine without the modal, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157315/loading-images-into-jssor-slider-from-a-while-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the script file again, it will override several variables such as `modal`, `btn`, `span`. After running this page, `modal` will be assigned last modal element. That makes every `btn.onclick` and `span.onclick` try to change last modal element.

If you use `var something` in global scope, it makes all the problem. In JS, it can be solved vary techniques such as a scope, closure, IIFE. (each keywords are very important if you want to use JS.)

```
function btn_onclick(modal) {
    return function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    };
}

function span_onclick(modal) {
    return function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    };
}

function window_onclick(modal) {
    return function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
    };
}
```

These 3 functions return new function which we need to use and also each functions are captured modal in their scope.

You can use something like below:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal_'+slider_counter2);
var btn = document.getElementById('modalopener_'+slider_counter2);
var span = document.getElementById('modal_close_btn_'+slider_counter2);

btn.onclick = btn_onclick(modal);
span.onclick = span_onclick(modal);
window.onclick = window_onclick(modal);
```

It is working code but not a good solution because it's a duplicated code. You can handle the event more affordable using jQuery or other event handling library/package.

Comment: hey your answer is working... only thing is second function should be none... (to close the window)... still trying to figure out how to close if clicked anywhere outside the modal...  what would be a better way to do this... (ajax call) .. i think ajax call will put unnecessary load on the server when data is already there in the query... what do u think...

Comment: @DragonFire general modal looks simple but they need to do some several thing such as closing action. Most of thing requires stylesheets and welformed html structure for reusability. Probably you can find some creating modal tutorial. Easy way is that grep some cool modal library if it's an option.

Comment: do u think it should be done like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130223/display-jssor-slider-inside-a-modal-window